# Netbeans Jar file with .java, not .class files

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I'm trying to make a jar file through Netbeans, I can use the Clean & Build option and a new jar file will be made in my project directory. However I need to submit these jar files for homework assignments and they need to have the .java source files in them, not the .class files. My classmates generally use eclipse and have no problem, but I have not been able to find a solution in Netbeans.

I am using Netbeans 8.2 with Java 1.8.0_161.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you need to submit both the class and java files or just the java files - seems a bit weird to just submit the java files

Comment: I just need to submit a jar file that will execute the program I just created that uses .java files instead of the .class files. The .class files in the jar are just jibberish to the grader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just need to submit a jar file that will execute the program I just created that uses .java files instead of the .class files. The .class files in the jar are just jibberish to the grader.

Doesn't make sense.  In order to execute the JAR, you need the `.class` files, that's what gets executed.

I would go back to your lecture and clarify what they mean

If you need to "also" include the `.java` files, then you can do the following:

Right click on the project node, select "Properties" from the popup menu

[image: Properties popup]

From the properties dialog, got to "Build | Packaging"

[image: Properties Dialog]

Change the "Exclude From JAR File" to remove the `**/*.java` from the available list of options.  This should now include the .java files in the generated JAR

Comment: That's probably what they meant, that worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: Is there a way to do this by default for all new projects created?

Comment: Off the top of my head, no, but, you might be able to build a project template which does it, but I've never done this myself